# CKeditor select the upload tab in image dialog by default

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is there a way to modify the image dialog of CKEditor to display the upload tab by default instead of the Image info tab?

I've tried doing this by adding a line of code to the onload of the dialog:

```
onLoad: function() {
    this.getDialog().selectPage('Upload');
}
```

this seems to work fine, I'm able to upload the image to the server, but as soon as I hit the ok button I get a permission denied error.

I've also tried it the way [CKSource describes](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Default_Dialog_Tab) but this gives me an exception since it overrides the onShow method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, the example in the docs is broken because the Image plugin already has an onShow() method.

The trick is to chain the methods like this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(e) {
    if (e.data.name == 'image') {
        var dialog = e.data.definition;
        oldOnShow = dialog.onShow;
        dialog.onShow = function() {
             oldOnShow.apply(this, arguments);
             this.selectPage('Upload');
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want CKEditor not to switch to the upload tab when double clicking on an image add this:`if(this.imageEditMode === false) { this.selectPage('Upload'); }`

Comment: Good ! i had to use `'upload'` instead of `'Upload'`

Comment: If you can an **assignment to undeclared variable oldOnShow** error change `oldOnShow =` to `var oldOnShow =`

Answer (score 5):

Fixed this by adding `this.selectPage('Upload');` to the end of the onShow function of the image plugin

Comment: This answer suggests modifying the core ckeditor files, which may work but will be a maintenance issue the next time ckeditor is updated your changes will go. The answer below by Roger Keays is the correct way to handle the default tab. Make note of the comment by elm.

Answer (score 1):

This doc explains how to set a dialog tab by default in your ckeditor config:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Default_Dialog_Tab

Comment: This link is not working . showing Msg "Sorry! This site is experiencing technical difficulties."

Answer (score 0):

Can user following script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {

    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'image') {
        dialogDefinition.onShow = function () {
            // This code will open the Upload tab.
            this.selectPage('Upload');
        };
    }
});
</script>
```